# Query Related to Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What is the best way to create a powershell script to search the entire AD users to get the list of users that does not have a home directory or home drive assigned in its properties, and save its samaccountname in a variable stack and by looping through each name - create its home drive folder

THIS WOULD BE LIKE THIS I SUPPOSE

```
 $c = get-ADUser -filter * -searchbase -properties 
    foreach($b in $c)
    {
    New-item -path
    }
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LDAPFilter` parameter to find all the users who have no or blank home directory attributes:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!(profilePath=*))" | ForEach-Object {
    $Username = $_.SAMAccountName
    $NewHomeDir = New-Item -Path "\\homedir\root\path" -ItemType Directory -Name $Username
    if($?){
        Set-ADUser $_ -ProfilePath $NewHomeDir.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: so how exactly ldap filter different?

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { # some filter }` will return ALL users from the domain controller, and then filter them on the client side. The LDAP filter I've shown returns *only* the relevant users from the Domain Controller. You could also use `Get-ADUser -Filter {ProfilePath -notlike "*"}`, it would get translated to a similar LDAP filter internally

Comment: Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!(HomeDirectory=*))    

will this work in a similar fashion?

Comment: Yes, it would (almost any ldap attribute can be filtered by its displayname), but the `homeDirectory` is kind of an ancient relic of the past (see http://serverfault.com/questions/29948/difference-between-profile-and-home-path)

Comment: Got it, ill deal with that, thanks!

suppose I want to add a key here,  like I want to keep an exception for the users with a specific property same (to make their home drives at some other path) so how can I embed this with the existing code, such that it does not disturb its current function.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand. Maybe ask a new question, before this comment thread turns into a novel :)

Comment: this is related, asking a new question would unnecessarily increase threads or very less value.

actually what i am trying to say is - 
after this filter searches for the appropriate threads, objects with a specific property same (suppose City) can be taken out from the result and be given a different path.

Comment: Again, not entirely sure I understand what you mean. Ask a new question and state clearly what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$SAMs = Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties ProfilePath | ? {$_.ProfilePath -eq $Null} | Select SamaccountName

foreach ($SAM in $SAMs)
{
$NewDir = New-Item $SAM -Type Directory -Path "ChooseYourPath" ## Create the Folder in desired path
Set-ADUser $SAM -ProfilePath $NewDir.FullName ## Set the AD User Account ProfilePath Property with the New Folder
}
```